# How to serialize to JSON from c# classes

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following classes in ASP.NET MVC using C# derived from a Json Model using VS menu Edit > Paste Special > Paste Json as Classes. 
I want to apply my own data. How can a create my data model, instead of using Rootobject obj = new Rootobject { properties here....},  so i can serialize it into a View Controller? Is there any better aprroach of doing it with EF, for example ?

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string MerchantOrderId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Authenticate { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public Debitcard DebitCard { get; set; }
}

public class Debitcard
{
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Holder { get; set; }
    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string SecurityCode { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize it into Json as the same output below but with my own data from the generated classes above:

```
{  
   "MerchantOrderId":"2014121201",
   "Customer":{  
      "Name":"Comprador Cartão de débito"
   },
   "Payment":{  
     "Type":"DebitCard",
     "Authenticate": true,
     "Amount":15700,
     "ReturnUrl":"http://www.cielo.com.br",
     "DebitCard":{  
         "CardNumber":"4551870000000183",
         "Holder":"Teste Holder",
         "ExpirationDate":"12/2030",
         "SecurityCode":"123",
         "Brand":"Visa"
     }
   }
}
```

Into a View Controller using the expression:

```
return Json(MyModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As for the serialization, the newtonsoft site covers this pretty well: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm  I'm not sure about the View part of the question.

Comment: Your `return Json(...);` does just exactly that (except by default it uses `JavascriptSerializer`, not `JSON.Net`) - what problems are you having?

Comment: @Ryan the problem in those examples is that they generated the model data into arrays ( List ) showing in this case the [] into the JSON but the model provided in my question does not contains array.

Comment: @Stephen i edited my question.

Comment: @Stephen, you are right about using JSON.NET, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

**1.** in controller

```
  public ActionResult ....()
  {
        var rootobject =new Rootobject();
        //set values
        ...
        ...
        return Json(new
        {
            Rootobject= rootobject
        });
  }
```

**2.** in js

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: //url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
        error: function (err) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            var rootobject =data.Rootobject;
            ...
            ...
        },
        async: true
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Saeed, but i want to use another approach as Json custom obj, for example , or any other.

Comment: I will give a try. Thank you